# Find "hubs" in a text-data correlation matrix from fuzzywuzzy

Tags: python, adjacency-matrix, fuzzywuzzy, fuzzy-comparison

If I have a list of strings, how do I select some 'representative' strings such that between them, they can fuzzy match with all of the strings in the list.

The first step, fuzzy matching all the texts has been done and it looks like this

[image]

My idea is to select two or three strings that can act as a representative for the whole set such that if I fuzzy match, I can flag all of them as 1 with a >80 threshold.

Is there a way I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

First, build the binary adjacency matrix of the graph A_ij=1 if fuzzymatch(i,j)>80, 0 otherwise. If you don't care about having a minimal set, you can use a greedy algorithm

```
#V is wordset nodes, initialize Hubset
Hubset = {}

while {x for x in V x not in Hubset and sum([A[x][j] for j in Hubset]) == 0}:
    #Choose "most central node" c in V(e.g. one with most connections to elements not already connected to Hubset)
    Hubset.add(c)
    
return Hubset
```

The minimal set problem can be formulated as a linear integer program, you can use a MLP solver for this:

```
Variables: x_1...x_n (x_i 1 if i in hub, 0 if not in hub)  
minimize sum_i x_i
subject to
sum_i A[i][j]x_i>=1 for all j (j constraints)
```

See the [networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/centrality.html) documentation for some measures of graph centrality

Comment: Hi! Python is giving me a syntax error for both the while condition stage and the hubset.add place since 'c' has not been defined anywhere? I changed it to this -

`while {x for x in domain_names x not in Hubset and sum([am.iloc[x,j] for j in Hubset]) == 0}:
    Hubset.add(x)`

Comment: You need to replace the comment section with some centrality measure in order to find c. You should try and experiment here, i suggested one option.